# echo select option data attribute value after form submit

Tags: php, html

I have a form that have select tag which i need to print the data-course attribute for the multiple options that the user selected after hitting the submit button where the H6 tag is

```
<h5>Course Selection</h5>

<?php if ($data_submitted != null) : ?>
   <h6><?php  foreach ($_POST['job_applied'] as $selectedOption) echo $selectedOption."\n"; ?></h6>
<?php else : ?>
   <select name="job_applied" id="multi_limit" multiple="multiple" class="multiselect form-control">
       <option value="10" data-course="Infromation Technology Course Credit">Infromation Technology Course Credit(10)</option>
       <option value="20" data-course="Main Stream Technologies Credit" >Main Stream Technologies Credit(20)</option>
       <option value="30" data-course="Mechanical Engineering Course" >Mechanical Engineering Course Credit(30)</option>
       <option value="40" data-course="General Mechanics Course Credit" >General Mechanics Course Credit(40)</option>
       <option value="50" data-course="Engineering Pro" >Engineering Pro Credit(50)</option>
       <option value="60" data-course="Master Engineering" >Master Engineering Credit(60)</option>
   </select>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an array that links the numeric value to the text.

```
<?php
$course_info = [
       10 => 'Infromation Technology Course Credit',
       20 => 'Main Stream Technologies Credit',
       30 => 'Mechanical Engineering Course Credit',
       40 => 'General Mechanics Course Credit',
       50 => 'Engineering Pro Credit',
       60 => 'Master Engineering Credit',
];
?>
```

Then you can pull the text from the array that matches the submitted values when the form is submitted. I also showed how you can use the same array to generate the select options, which can be advantageous because it prevents the kinds of problems you have when you store the same data in two places (change one and forget to change the other, etc.), but you don't have to do that part for this to work.

```
<h5>Course Selection</h5>

<?php if ($data_submitted != null) : ?>
    <h6>
    <?php foreach ($_POST['job_applied'] as $selectedOption) {
           // get the text that matches the numeric value that was submitted
           echo $course_info[$selectedOption]."\n";
       } ?>
   </h6>
<?php else : ?>
   <select name="job_applied" id="multi_limit" multiple="multiple" class="multiselect form-control">
       <?php foreach ($course_info as $id => $name) {
           echo "<option value='$id' data-course='$name'>$name($id)</option>";
       } ?>
   </select>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do this, I'd personally keep an array on the server-side which contains this information, **however**, I'm not going to show you that, I'm showing a way to grab the content of he `data-course` attrubutes.

**So here's that method...**

The trouble is, when you post a form, only the `name` and it's `value/s` are posted. There are no options to post other attributes.

You'll have to intercept the submission of the form with javascript, and post the data yourself, this sample below is assuming you are using jQuery.

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function(){

  $('form').on('submit', function (e){
    e.preventDefault(); // Stop posting to the server
    var selectedOptions = $('select[name="job_applied"] option:selected'); // Get all the selected options

    // Loop through them
    $.each(selectedOptions, function(i,o){
      // and append a hidden input with a job_applied_meta[data-course][****] name attribute
      // NOTE: The **** above is the value from the selected option.
      $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="job_applied_meta[data-course]['+$(this).attr('value')+']" value="'+$(this).attr('data-course')+'">')
    })

    // Now post the form
    $('form').submit();
  });

});
</script>
```

The above will now submit the data-course attribute to the server, but it will be contained in `$_POST['job_applied_meta']`.

`$_POST['job_applied_meta']['data-course']` will be an array, something like this:

```
array(
   '10' => 'Infromation Technology Course Credit',
   '40' => 'General Mechanics Course Credit'
);
```

Which you would then access like this:

```
<?php 
    foreach ($_POST['job_applied'] as $selectedOption) {
       echo $_POST['job_applied_meta']['data-course'][ $selectedOption ]; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: I think they haven't specifically asked how to post the data-course attribute, just how to print it, but this looks like it would do the job just as well. Adding the hidden inputs is an interesting way to do it, I wouldn't have thought of that. 

Comment: Ahhh yes you're right, I must have read it wrong, I'll edit, cheers!

Comment: It's a nice answer regardless. Sorry for nitpicking :-)

Comment: Worked great thanks but the php solution was better suited for my needs appreciate your help

Comment: No worries, as mentioned in my post I also prefer the solution to have the array on the server.